# Removing various states/provinces from shipping but not billing address

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, state

I've searched all around and haven't been able to find a solution to this.

I'm on Magento 2.1.7 and need to remove the option for shipping to any province other than Ontario (Canada) from my check-out page. But at the same time I need billing addresses from other provinces to be accepted, just no shipments to anywhere other than Ontario.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This related answer using a Plugin works better if you just want to remove these from ALL the address forms: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/137302/48243

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to change it in the checkout for example create these module files

Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Directory\Helper\Data as DirectoryHelper;

/**
 * Class LayoutProcessor
 * @package Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout
 */
class LayoutProcessor implements \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface
{


    /**
     * @var DirectoryHelper
     */
    protected $directoryHelper;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     * @param DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper
    ) {
        $this->directoryHelper = $directoryHelper;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($result)
    {

        if ($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
        ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']) {



                    $shippingAddressFieldSet = $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
                    ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];

                    $regionOptions = $shippingAddressFieldSet['region_id']['options'];

                    // update the options array according to your logic $regionOptions

                    $shippingAddressFieldSet['region_id']['options'] = $regionOptions;

                    $result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']
                    ['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'] = $shippingAddressFieldSet;
                }
            }
        }


        return $result;
    }
}
```

and then your frontend di

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_module_layoutprocessor" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove from shipping and billing adress form, you can try this code

```
namespace Vendor\CheckoutScripts\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessorInterface;

class LayoutProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $component = &$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children'];
        $componentBilling = &$component['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
        foreach ($componentBilling as $keyBilling => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/-form/', $keyBilling)) { 
                unset($componentBilling[$keyBilling]['children']['form-fields']['children']['region_id']);
            }
        }

        $componentShipping = &$component['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'];
        if(!empty($componentShipping['region_id'])) {
            unset($componentShipping['region_id']);
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**=> frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="layoutProcessors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_checkoutscripts_layoutprocessor" xsi:type="object">Vendor\CheckoutScripts\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```