# Remove some states from dropdown on billing step on magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I need to remove some states/regions from the checkout dropdown in the billing step, and different states/regions from the shipping step on Magento 2.2.
I have used this
[How to remove Guam, Palau, and other US Territories from address State dropdown - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137284/how-to-remove-guam-palau-and-other-us-territories-from-address-state-dropdown?rq=1)

it works but it removes them from both shipping and billing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Guam, Palau, and other US Territories from address State dropdown - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137284/how-to-remove-guam-palau-and-other-us-territories-from-address-state-dropdown)

Comment: the problem is that it removes from both shipping and billing step, for example i need to remove Alaska just from shipping step, and remove in example Guam just from billing step

Comment: did you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

1. log in to admin
2. Go to **stores > configuration > General > General > States options (Choose Required Country from drop down)** from here
3. Save configuration
4. Go to PHPMYADMIN > choose table **directory_country_region_name** and **directory_country_region**
5. Delete the particular desired record from that table. (You have to do it from the database. Otherwise, you have to use all existing state options. Why because **The states were added already right?** To make any change, you need to access the database.)
6. Clear cache and re-index

Answer (score 0):

I have removed them from the shipping step and I know this is not the perfect solution but we only ship to the US so it works fine for me.

create a module and create `Model\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Checkout;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }



    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['region_id'] =
                [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select', 
                    'id' => 'region-state',
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.region_id',
                'label' => 'State/Province',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => ['required-entry' => true,],
                'sortOrder' => 80,
                'id' => 'region-state',
                'options' => [

                [
                    'value' => '',
                    'label' => 'Please select region state or province.',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => '12',
                    'label' => 'California',
                ],
                [
                    'value' => '13',
                    'label' => 'Colorado',
                ]
                ],
            ];  
    return $jsLayout;

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection">
           <plugin name="product_Limit_State_Filter_Plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\StateFilter"/>
      </type>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Plugin/StateFilter.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class StateFilter
{
  protected $disallowed = [
    'Guam',
    'Armed Forces Pacific',
    'Hawaii',
    'Alaska'
];
  protected $scopeConfig;
  protected $allowedUsStates;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
  ) {
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
      $this->session = $session;
  }

  public function afterToOptionArray($subject, $options)
  {
      $result = array_filter($options, function ($option) {
          if (isset($option['label'])){
            // if($this->needHide()) { //remove this condition to hide them by default
              return !in_array($option['label'], $this->disallowed);
            // }
          }
          return true;
      });
      return $result;
  }

  public function needHide() {
    $blacklistSkus = array('sku1','sku2');
    $needToHide = false;
    $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
    if($quote->getAllItems()) {
      $items = $quote->getAllItems();
      foreach($items as $item) {
            if(in_array($item->getSku(),$blacklistSkus)) {
            $needToHide = true;         
        }
      }
    }
    return $needToHide;
  }
}
```