# Magento 2: Need to remove Alaska and Hawaii state for shipping state dropdown on checkout page

Tags: magento2

How to remove Alaska and Hawaii states for shipping state drop down on checkout page?

Comment: Please check with below url - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137284/how-to-remove-guam-palau-and-other-us-territories-from-address-state-dropdown?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

1. Login to admin
2. Go to **stores > configuration > General > General > States options (Choose Required Country from drop down)** from here
3. Save configuration
4. Go to PHPMYADMIN > choose table **directory_country_region_name** and **directory_country_region**
5. Delete the particular desired record from that tables. (You have to do from the database. Otherwise, you have to use all existing state options. Why because **The states were added already right?** To make any change, you need to access the database.)
6. Clear cache and re-index

Comment: Please describe in brief. How i can do?

Comment: I can't delete from database. Any alternate solution?

Comment: No I can't remove from database

Comment: @Shiwani, no have to remove from DB